# Why is my script running the animation, but not showing it?

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I am trying to do a simple animation on a line.  The basic goal here is that when I click on the canvas, the line goes from being a point to being a certain amount of pixels tall.  However, when I click on the canvas, the script shows that the animation started and completed(the callback function is called at the end), but I don't actually see the animation happening.  Can anyone tell me why?

Function creates each animated line, appends it to the document, and sets the style

```
function animatedLine(name, x1, y1, width, height, stroke, duration){
    this.name = name;
    this.x1 = x1;
    this.y1 = y1;
    this.stroke = stroke;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height,
    this.duration = duration;

    $("body").append("<div id='" +this.name +"'></div>");
    $("#" +this.name).css({"position": "absolute", "top": this.y1 +"px", "left": this.x1 +"px", "backgroundColor": this.stroke, "width": this.width +"px", "height": this.y1 +"px", "z-index": 5});
}
```

Creates an new `animatedLine` object

```
var line1 = new animatedLine("R01", 0, 0, 5, 100, "black", 3);
```

Creates the timeline

```
var timeline = new TimelineLite();
```

Creates the timeline animation, this is clearly happening because `onComplete` function is being called

```
timeline.to(line1, line1.duration, {"height": line1.height +"px",
    onComplete: function(){
```

Once the animation has completed, "hello" is printed to the console

```
        console.log("hello");
    }
});

$("#schematic_holder").on("click", function(){
    timeline.play();
})
```

Something to note, the background is a canvas element and its position is set to absolute and z-index is set to 0, so the line should be layering itself on top of the canvas, which it is doing.

Comment: Welcome to SO, do you mind editing your question and change the uppercase to lowercase?

Comment: @Huangism sure thing.  I just did that for commenting purposes, but realize that now is redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are tweening line1 (the AnimatedLine "class" that created the #R01 element).

What you want to tween is #R01 (the div element).

```js
function animatedLine(name, x1, y1, width, height, stroke, duration){
  this.name = name;
  this.x1 = x1;
  this.y1 = y1;
  this.stroke = stroke;
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height,
  this.duration = duration;

  $("body").append("<div id='" +this.name +"'></div>");
  $("#" +this.name).css({
    "position": "absolute",
    "top": this.y1 +"px",
    "left": this.x1 +"px",
    "backgroundColor": this.stroke,
    "width": this.width +"px",
    "height": this.y1 +"px",
    "z-index": 5
  });

}

var line1 = new animatedLine("R01", 0, 0, 5, 100, "black", 3);

var timeline = new TimelineLite();

timeline.to("#R01", line1.duration, {
  "height": line1.height +"px",
  onComplete: function(){ console.log("hello"); }
});

timeline.play();
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/plugins/CSSPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TimelineLite.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenLite.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```